# WP7 UserControl with conditional Converter?

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, windows-phone-7, converters

I'm developing a UserControl to manipulate numeric data, but I'd like to be able to specify the numeric format string (or even the Converter itself) per instance of the UC.

I tried adding a property to my UC and binding that to the Converter, but ran into errors.

It seems that binding to the converter is not possible in the version of SL that runs on WP7. I read that custom controls in SL support more customization.

But, do I really need to go that deep just to support this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything that you can do with a converter that you can't do in an underlying view model instead. In fact, if you have converters in a Data Template for items in a list, this is known to impact scrolling performance and so using a view model is preferable.

Given the dynamic nature of your requirements I think trying an approach other than using a view model is likely to give you headache. If you aren't already using an MVVM framework/toolkit, you may want to look at Laurent Bugnion's [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/).

Answer (score 1):

If by binding to the converter, you mean binding to the converter parameter, you can't do this in SL4, or even WPF!

I think you are going to have to do a bit more work in code behind, possibly using a view model. You can localise the view model to just this user control (see [the following article](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/08/the-mini-viewmodel-pattern/)), so do not need to use MVVM throughout your entire application.